# jQuery Form Plugin posting array as string

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using the jQuery Form Plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and trying to post an array to a php file to be processed, but I can't get to work as intended.

With regular jQuery `$.ajax` the code example:

```
var a = [1,2,3];

$.ajax({
    url: "uploader.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({
        a: a
    })
});
```

would output the PHP variable `$_POST['a']` as

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

With the plugin the output of `$_POST['a']` is a string that equals "1,2,3".

I want the plugin to act like `$.ajax` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be handy to see your code that sets up the jQuery form plugin, but if you're doing a drop-in replacement I assume its something like:

```
$('#myFormId').ajaxForm({
  url: uploader.php, 
  type: "POST", 
  data:({
    a:a
  })
});
```

Without checking I've just assumed that "data" gets merged with the form data by the jquery Form plugin

I'm guessing the ajax form plugin just calls the toString javascript method on `a` - which would give "1,2,3"

To get a JSON string you could do JSON.stringify(a). Ie:

```
$('#myFormId').ajaxForm({
  url: uploader.php, 
  type: "POST", 
  data:({
    a:JSON.stringify(a)
  })
});
```

Not sure that will work - but its worth a try

Comment: This certainly works and can be easily decoded with PHP. I was originally thinking I was overlooking an option for the plugin that would stop it converting the array to a comma separated string, but I now think controlling how the array is processed myawlf is a more practical idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your array to a string and then parse it in your php script

JQuery

```
var a = [1,2,3];

$.ajax({
    url: "uploader.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({
        a: $.param(a);
    })
});
```

PHP

```
parse_str( $_POST['a'] , $paramsArray );
```